# Usage of 'consequently to' in a scientific article

Tags: phrases, word-usage

In a scientific context, can you say "consequently to"? e.g....depicting a gradual re-organisation of these tracts consequently to the gradual loss of coverage.

Comment: My immediate thinking is that neither *consequently to* nor *consequent to* are normal usage. I would typically think it should be rephrased: *There was a gradual loss of coverage and a consequent reorganization of these tracts.* Or: *There was a gradual loss of coverage and, consequently, a reorganization of these tracts.* Or: "*There was a gradual reorganization of these tracts as a consequence of the loss of coverage.*

Comment: I cannot understand your question, although the answer is clearly no as the phrase is unintelligible. When you write "consequently to" do you mean "because of". If so use the simple familiar Anglo-Saxon if you wish your scientific writing to be understood. Just as you should never write "prior to" when you mean "before", or "subsequent to" when you mean "after".

Comment: @David [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prior+to+1900%2Cbefore+1900&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprior%20to%201900%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%201900%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprior%20to%201900%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%201900%3B%2Cc0) seem to back you up; prior to 1900, there was more of a choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You must have been spending too much time in priories.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Consequently" does not mean simply "it happened after some action." Consequently means that it happened after an action and was caused by that action.

Example: He touched the hot stove; consequently, he burned his fingers.

You may be thinking of "subsequently", which means afterwards but without implied causation.

Example: Coverage gradually diminished. Subsequently, the tracts were reorganized. (The diminution of coverage did not, by itself, accomplish the reorganization.)

There's a logical fallacy called "post hoc, ergo prompter hoc" that means it happened after that, therefore it was caused by that. The misuse of "consequently" is confusing in the same way.

Comment: Why assume that the reorganization is not a result of the loss?

Answer (score 0):

No, *consequently* is an adverb and needs to modify a verb. To be grammatical, that sentence should read

> depicting a gradual re-organisation of these tracts consequent to the gradual loss of coverage,

and what it would mean is

> depicting a gradual re-organisation of these tracts resulting from the gradual loss of coverage,

which may not be what you want it to mean.

Finally, using the more common *resulting from* rather than the rare *consequent to* would probably make it more comprehensible, and thus be better style. See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consequent+to%2C+resulting+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconsequent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresulting%20from%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconsequent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresulting%20from%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: *Consequent on* or *consequent upon* for this speaker of British English.